# Write a program that prints the even number between [n-m]

Tags: java, while-loop

using while loops only i need a program that reads 2 integers n, m (n<= m) and prints all even numbers between n and m (inclusive.) For example if the input values are 2 and 9 the output must be 2 4 6 8. Or for the input 3 and 12 the program must produce 4 6 8 10 12.

This is what I imagine, but it does not work!

Please help!!!!

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter an integer value-> ");
    int k = input.nextInt();
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a larger value-> ");
    int j = input.nextInt();
    int i = 1;

    while (i >= k) {
      System.out.println(i); 
      i = i + 2;
      System.out.println(i);
      if (i < j) {
        i = i + 2;
        System.out.println(i);
      }
    }
```

Comment: why are you working with `i`, when you declare the range with `k` and `j`?

Comment: I love it. Question uses `n` and `m`, but developer uses `k` and `j`. That's not confusing at all ;-)

Comment: I am glad you find it funny

Comment: I used i  as the number I am changing, since k and j are the inputs

Comment: My point is that everything you do that causes confusion makes the real problem harder to find. You have to keep `m`, `n`, `j`, `k` and `i` in your thoughts when you don't need so many...  `int i = 1;    while (i >= k) {` - hope k is always <= 1...

Comment: Ok, now I understand you better

Comment: then you should start with `int i = j;` afterwards you could check if `j % 2 == 0`, if it´s not the case increment `i` by 1. Afterwards simply print `i` and do `i+=2` in a loop.

Comment: Maybe you don t realize that I am learning and obviously confused, that is why i ask for help, so that i can see these things.

Comment: Thanks Kevin I will try and report findings lol

Answer (score 3):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter an integer value-> ");
int k = input.nextInt();
input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a larger value-> ");
int j = input.nextInt();
int i = k;
if(i % 2 == 1)
    i++;

while (i <= j) {
    System.out.println(i); 
    i = i + 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! this also works

Comment: @KelvinLai you do not need line `input = new Scanner(System.in);` that is called initiation of object which in this case you do not need

Comment: ok, thanks very much

Comment: what if I wanted for loops instead of while, I am trying to see the use of all these different methods, so that i can learn them and know how to apply them

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I have modified `int i = k`, while loop condition `i < = j` & added logic for even number

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter an integer value-> ");
    int k = input.nextInt();
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a larger value-> ");
    int j = input.nextInt();
    int i = k;

    while (i <= j) {
       if (i%2 == 0) {
           System.out.println(i);
       }
       i++;
    }
```

Comment: you could check if `i` is odd before the loop, and simply add two to `i` after every iteration.

Comment: Thanks guys, This helps..... question.... so i gets the value of k right? so when i check if i is less than equal to j, it confirms that only? then checks if the remainder is 0 when i divide by 2,which gives me the even numbers. now which part makess sure that 8 is also present?

Answer (score 2):

I did it with `for` , but maybe i'm late lol

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter an integer value-> ");
int k = input.nextInt();

System.out.print("Enter a larger value-> ");
int j = input.nextInt();

for (int i=k;i<=j; i++){
        if (i%2 == 0){
        System.out.println(i);
        } 
}
```

Comment: hahahaha, thanks, i did fixed the problem, but i appreciate your answer!

Comment: it must be with `while` .. damn .. i didnt read it .. lol

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution with little bit of help so you can learn

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter an integer value-> ");
int k = input.nextInt();
// >> input = new Scanner(System.in); do not need this line
System.out.print("Enter a larger value-> ");
int j = input.nextInt();
// int i = 1; you do not need extra value you can reuse k

if ( k % 2 != 0){ // number is odd
   ++k
}

while(k < j) {
  System.out.println("" + k);
  k += 2;
}
```

Comment: ooohhhhh i see what you mean, so many different ways of doing this

Comment: thanks, i will try everything and see what works best.